# How do we know that $\psi(n)=\psi(1)\cdot n$ is the only isomorphism in $\mathbb{Z}_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

What's the proof that the only bijective group automorphism (or isomorphism) in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is in form $\psi(n)=\psi(1)\cdot n$, where $\psi(n)\in\mathbb{Z}_n$?

If it so, can be this generalized to any finite group (e.g. $\psi(n)=(\psi(1))^n$ for group $S_n$)?

Comment: Hint: $\phi(n) = \phi(\underbrace{1+1+\cdots + 1}_{n\text{ times}})$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth I still don't see why this isomorphism is unique.

Comment: are you sure all the times you use $n$ are the same $n$? In $\mathbb{Z}_n$ you have $n=0$ and $x\cdot n=0$ for all $x$, so $\phi(n)=\phi(0)=0=\phi(1)\cdot n$

Comment: To show that this is the unique form for an isomorphism, you basically have to suppose that $\phi$ is an isomorphism, then proceed to show that $\phi$ has that form. Are you able to make any progress in doing this?

Comment: The notation is really a bad choice. $\phi(n)$ usually is Euler's totient function.

Comment: The question is very confusing. The formula uses "$n$" which is the same as in "$\mathbb{Z}_n$". Also what's the difference between "$\phi$" and "$\psi$"? And no, there is no such thing as "unique" automorphism. Every group of order at least $3$ has at least $2$ different automorphisms. And finally: no, this cannot be generalized to any (finite or not) group. This works **only** for cyclic groups. Simply because the formula doesn't even fully define the homomorphism when the group is non-cyclic.

Answer (score 1):

It's not unique. Since $1$ and $2$ both generate $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$, the identity map and the map sending $1\mapsto 2$, $2\mapsto 1$ and $0\mapsto 0$, you can check, are both automorphisms, and they are different.

However, both of these maps *are* uniquely determined by the image of $1$. Perhaps this is what you should be checking: that any automorphism of a cyclic group is determined by the image of a generator.